# In the process of Bel-robisons tensor: identity for $R_{amnk} R_{b}^{\phantom{b}mnk} = \frac{1}{4} g_{ab} R_{dmnk} R^{dmnk}$

Tags: gravity

Recently, i an starting to study some subject related with Bel-Robinson tensor. 
In the process of computing its some basic properties i noticed i need to prove following identity which holds on vacuum.

$R_{amnk} R_{b}^{\phantom{b}mnk} = \frac{1}{4} g_{ab} R_{dmnk} R^{dmnk}$

or equivalently

$g_{ab} R_{\mu \lambda \sigma \tau} R_{\nu}^{\phantom{a} \lambda \sigma \tau}
= g_{\mu\nu} R_{a\lambda \sigma \tau} R_{b}^{\phantom{b} \lambda \sigma \tau}$

Can you give me some idea to compute above identity?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you explain exactly how this kind of tensor ( e.g $R_{dmnk}$ or R^{dmnk} ) are produced?!

Comment: @asaa, $R_{dmnk}$ is usual Riemann tensor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from

\begin{align}
    R_{almn} R_{b}^{\phantom{\b} lmn}  = g_{ab} A 
\end{align}
This can be constructed by considering free index and symmetric properties.

Thus by contraction we obtain coefficients $A$

For $D=4$, $g_{ab} g^{ab}=4$, thus $A= \frac{1}{4} R_{dlmn}R^{dlmn}$